# Unable to View Audit Logs for Stream Firestore to BigQuery Extension

Tags: logging, google-bigquery, event-arc

I have installed Stream Firestore to BigQuery extension for one of collection, When I insert some records in that collection, it successfully move data from Firestore to BigQuery. But I am not able to view Logs of BigQuery Data Insertion in a table.

I have tried accessing Logs with different Roles like Logs Viewer, Logs Admin, and Private Logs Viewer.
When I insert some record in Table from Google Cloud Big Query Explorer, it generates the Logs as desired.

I want the logs from Extension to Trigger a 2nd Gen Cloud Function to perform some processing. Is there any other way of doing it?